# Railo error when trying to use CFC via AJAX

Tags: javascript, cfc, railo, cfml

I have been unable to get Railo to work with a new CFC on a test page and keep getting a "Railo is not defined" in the Error Console

The Error Console highlights this section:

```
   var _Railo_proxytest = Railo.ajaxProxy.init('/proxytest.cfc','proxytest');
```

Code CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>

   <cffunction name="test1" access="remote" returntype="string" output="no">
   <cfargument name="name" type="string" required="yes" default="Nameless">
   <cfreturn "#areguments.name#">
   </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Code CFM:

```
<cfajaxproxy cfc="proxytest" jsclassname ="proxytest">
<script>

var myProxy = new proxytest();

function runProxy() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var results = myProxy.sayHello(name);
}
</script>


<form>
  <input type="text" id ="name">
  <input type="button" onclick="runProxy()" value="Run">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var proxytest = Railo.ajaxProxy.init('/proxytest.cfc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in your example code: `<cfreturn "#areguments.name#">` should be `<cfreturn "#arguments.name#">`

Also, the code you posted doesn't add up. You are calling function `sayHello()` from Javascript, but the CFC does not have this function. It is usually wise to post the actual code, instead of a rewrite.

What happens if you call `/proxytest.cfc?method=test1&name=MyName` directly from the browser?